# Does setup.py actually load the packages to GCP Dataflow?

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

Here I am using setup.py to install dependencies for my dataflow job,
but in the GCP Dataflow Stackdriver error logs I am getting an error on downloading a package.

Does this below code when I run locally does dataflow have access to them irrelevant of which artifactory or pip server dataflow is linked to?

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import
 from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='DataflowpipelineDependencies',
  version='0.1',
  description='Dependencies',
  install_requires=[
    'google-cloud-storage==1.16.1',
    'jsonschema==2.6.0',
    'vm-cloudevents==0.1.0' // Private artifactory package
  ],
  packages = find_packages()
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your dependencies with [`--setup_file`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) option.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing (as you can see above), but I have a package dependency that isn't publicly available. I am asking if GCP Dataflow gets those packages in the template creation somehow. 
The docs aren't  clear on this.

Comment: Yeah, the docs don't mention much, but just above [this section](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers#troubleshooting), you'll see it says, "Common issues:  If your job has extra Python dependencies **from a private PyPi mirror** and can't be pulled by a remote Cloud Build job, try using the **local docker** option or try building your container using a **Dockerfile**". I have the same issue and I'm trying to resolve it, too.  I haven't completed it yet, so I cannot say if the solution works for me yet.